# has_many at two levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.5.

Company has many users. User has many emails addresses. Association tables are company_users and user_emails table.

I want to get all the email addresses for a company. What is the most efficient way to get that?

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of Company add the line:

```
has_many :emails, :through => :users
```

Now all Company objects have an `emails` method, which returns all the emails of all the users of that company.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
has_many :emails, :through => :users
```

Not sure if the association works on many-many-many, but it's worth a shot.  The documentation can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).